# How to detect mouse hover on NSButton. Obj-C, Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mouseevent, mousehover

I have a Mac application that has two NSButtons on each bottom corner of the window. I have set their `Alpha = .5` in the .xib. I want to know how to detect a mouse hover over the button and change the alpha to lets say .9. How do I do this? I suppose all you need to know from my code is the .h.

```
@property (unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet NSButton *leftButton;
@property (unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet NSButton *rightButton;
```

Those are synthesized in my .m. Deployment target is OS X 10.6+. Thanks.

**EDIT**

I really haven't tried anything. I have seen something on NSTrackingArea, but am not positive on how to use it, more importantly, I was wondering if there was another way to go about it. Such as an event that is already called or something.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: At the moment nothing. I looked around for a little bit, I did find something on NSTrackingArea, but am not positive how to use it. Also I was wondering if there was a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to Subclass the NSButton class (or even better the NSButtonCell class).

```
- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
```

They should get called when the mouse enter and exit the area. You may also need to re create the tracking area, look here:

```
- (void)updateTrackingAreas
```

For fade in and fade out effect I played with animator and alpha value for example:

```
[[self animator]setAlphaValue:0.9];
```

EDIT: This is just for reference, so that you can take some ideas

```
@interface MyButton : NSButton {
- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent;     
- (void)updateTrackingAreas;
@end
```

Comment: Now I would suggest you to look for books. For the time being, see this code in EDIT: and try to remember if you have basics of Obj-c